# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'connector' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, odoo-10

I have a error : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'connector' referenced before assignment. To self host, etc. I have declaration in my init.

```
class OdooUtility():
  connector = None
  driver = None

  def get_control(self):        
    try:
        connector= ODOO(self.host, port=self.port)
        connector.login(self.dbname, self.username, self.password)
    except Exception as e:
        print e.message

    control = connector.env['rm.control']
    control_ids = control.search([])
    c = control.browse(control_ids)
    res = []
    for row in c:
        res.append(row)
    return res
```

How can I fix this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're using `connector` in `connector.env['rm.control']`, but this is in the scope of the `get_control` function and in there, `connector` may not have been defined, if the `try` section throws an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to write `self.connector` or `OdooUtility.connector` instead of just `connector`.  I suspect `self.connector` is what you wanted.